# Самый быстрый метод сортировки массива в JS?

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой низкой производительности нативного `sort([])` в JavaScript. Профилировщик Google Chrome указывает мне, что этот код выполняется 38ms. К слову, замеченное мной время выполнения остального моего кода - максимум 14ms. Начал читать англоязычные статьи о том, почему же нативный `sort()` настолько медленный и как многие говорят, проблема в [GetThirdIndex()](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/0c76b0ae850027006d5ec0d92449e449d996d3bb/src/js/array.js#L744).

Какой на ваш взгляд сортировщик сможет быстрее всех справиться с этим кодом:

```
proposals_map = Object.keys(proposals).sort((a,b) => proposals[a].terms[Object.keys(proposals[a].terms)[0]].unified_price - proposals[b].terms[Object.keys(proposals[b].terms)[0]].unified_price);
```

Тест на [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/javascript-sort) говорит, что самый быстрый - InsertSort(то есть сортировка вставками), но сам бенчмарк-то простенький, не с многомерным массивом.

Comment: не пробовали преобразовать исходный массив в массив пар `[proposals[x].terms[Object.keys(proposals[x].terms)[0]].unified_price, x]`, затем отсортировать массив пар по первому элементу пары, затем преобразовать массив пар обратно?

Comment: Тормозит у вас не сортировка, а бесконечные вызовы `Object.keys(proposals[a].terms)[0]`. Подозреваю, что этого не нужно делать каждый раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере тормозит не алгоритм сортировки, а многочисленные вызовы `Object.keys`.

Надо уменьшить количество этих вызовов. Например так:

```
proposals_map = Object.keys(proposals)
    .map(key => {
        let terms = proposals[key].terms;
        let price = terms[Object.keys(terms)[0]].unified_price;
        return [key, price];
    })
    .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
    .map(item => item[0]);
```

Comment: С этим кодом всё стало ещё хуже. Если с моим кодом на странице происходит просто небольшой рывок, то с этим при сортировке ~3000 элементов страница может повиснуть на 2 пару секунд.

Comment: И тормозит именно сортировка?

Comment: https://jsperf.com/sort-test-735421 — тест с  3000 элементов по 100 terms в каждом

Comment: Спасибо. Благодаря вашему совету по многочисленным вызовам `Object.keys` смог оптимизировать не только этот кусок кода, но и все остальные в моём проекте. Посмотрел исходный код `Object.keys()` на github проекта V8, и, как оказалось, это просто функция, которая прогоняет ещё один `for(let object in objects)`, что и вызывало фриз страницы. Перестал вызывать `Object.keys()` в теле итератора, а просто закэшировал значение длинны массива с объектами перед и всё стало просто замечательно.