# Как отсортировать массив и получить на выходе ключи объектов

Tags: php

Есть следующий алгоритм, написанный мной на JS:

```
proposals_map = Object.keys(proposals).sort((a,b) => {
    proposals[a].terms[Object.keys(proposals[a].terms)[0]].unified_price - 
    proposals[b].terms[Object.keys(proposals[b].terms)[0]].unified_price
});
```

Этот код работает медленно, да и к тому же вызывает подёргивания на странице. Хочу переписать алгоритм на PHP, чтобы сортировка выполнялась на сервере и не грузила клиент. Чем и какими функциями можно реализовать подобное на PHP? Опишите, пожалуйста, алгоритм в двух словах.

**UDP:** результатом работы алгоритма должен быть не отсортированный массив, а ключи отсортированного массива.

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть какой у вас исходный массив(какой может быть..) и по каким критериям вы хотите отсортировать....

Comment: @Arsen пожалуйста. https://repl.it/NP0O

Comment: каков у вас объем этого массива, что тупит? да и мб как то это дело переписать можно для упрощения?

Comment: @teran да вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735421/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-js/735953?noredirect=1#comment1121569_735953) мне человек подсказал, что у меня проблемы из-за постоянного обращения к Object.keys и, дескать, это просаживает производительность(в профилировщике функция, в теле которой исполняется этот код - 38,9ms, что является максимальным значением вообще во всём проекте).

Comment: @teran но с его кодом у меня страница фризится ещё больше. Возможно потому, что в его решении целых два `.map()`, что просаживает производительность ещё больше. Хоть и работает быстрее.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin вы пример исходных данных и результата привели бы лучше, вам и подскажут, как его оптимально отсортировать

Comment: @teran я ссылку во втором комментарии оставил(на relp.it)

Answer (score 2):

Для сортироваки массива с сохранением ключей в php используется функция [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php). Для получения ключей - `array_keys()`

```
$result = array_keys(uasort($data, function($a, $b){ 
                       return $a['unified_price'] - $b['unified_price'];
               }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Например функцией [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)($a, "sorting");

```
function sorting($a, $b) {
    return unified_price - unified_price;
}
```

Comment: во-первых, на кой вам именованная функция. во вторых, код не валидный. в третьих, результат - сортированный массив, а не его ключи, как прошено у автора